# What is the natural map $E_D(\Bbb{Q})\times E(\Bbb{Q})\to E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E/\Bbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ be a quadratic field.If $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$, let $E_D:Dy^2=X^3+ax+b$.
　In this page, professor Silverman reads there is a natural map $E_D(\Bbb{Q})\times E(\Bbb{Q})\to E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))$.
But how can we define this map ?
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76413/torsion-subgroups-in-families-of-twists-of-elliptic-curves/76464?noredirect=1#comment1182446_76464

The map occurred to my mind is $(P,Q)\to P'+Q$($P'$ is a point corresponding to $P$ by an isomorphism $E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))\cong E_D(\Bbb{Q}))$, but then it seems difficult to find kernel and cockerel of this map.

Comment: For the kernel, if $P' + Q = 0$, then $P'=-Q\in E(\mathbb Q)$. If $P = (x, y)$, then $P' = (x,y\sqrt d )$, so this means $y = 0$, i.e. that $P\in E[2]$. Conversely, you can show that the kernel of the map is the diagonal image of $E[2](\mathbb Q)$ inside the product.

Comment: I think the cokernel might be a bit more subtle (although it will certainly be a finite group). For example it could be that the image of the map is something like $2\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Mathmo123. Thank you very much. Do you think Silverman suggests the same map of mine ?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that you mean the isomorphism from $E_D\to E$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)$, not an isomorphism $E(\mathbb Q(\sqrt D)\cong E_D(\mathbb Q)$, which need not exist!